# How to check whether a string date can be converted to a DateTime or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

There is a SQL Server 2008 database for which I have to create a management software. The database contains a column named DateOfCreation. The table designer made this column as string and gave freedom to users to add date in any format they want and this was really a silly mistake by him. Now some users added as "24 Jan" or
"Jan 24" or "1991 1 12" and many unknown formats. What I want is that when I fetch this string date, a function should be called that will check the format and return -1 if date is not in correct format else return the converted date in DD/MM/YYYY. So how can I check the format of the date that string date variable is containing?

Comment: What do you mean "check the format" and "return -1 if date is not in correct format." I thought you said it could be in any format?

Comment: You say that you want dd/mm/yyyy but if a user was free to enter any format they want, how do you know that 6/8/2012 is August 6th? What if the user meant June 8th? How do you expect SQL Server to know what the user meant?

Comment: I just want format applicability. If format is different it will show error otherwise it will parse the same. Whatever the date user entered it will parse to original and then user can update it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) with your date format, it will return false in case if the date format is different or invalid.

For multiple formats you can specify multiple formats in a string array and then use that in `DateTime.TryParseExact` something like:

[From MSDN - DateTime.TryParseExact Method (String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime%)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)

```
string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                   "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                   "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};
string[] dateStrings = {"5/1/2009 6:32 PM", "05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM", 
                        "5/1/2009 6:32:00", "05/01/2009 06:32", 
                        "05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM", "05/01/2009 06:32:00"}; 
DateTime dateValue;

foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
{
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue))
      Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
   else
      Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) could help to some extent. However, you would be dependent on your user using an appropriate date/time format.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Tuple<bool, DateTime> GetDateTime(string x)
{
DateTime DT = null;
return Tuple.Create((DateTime.TryParse(x, out DT)), DT)
}
```

may work. I can't guarantee it though.

Comment: Mind you that DateTime is not nullable and `DateTime DT = null;`will not compile